# How to post to a join table in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-relations

I am trying to add to a many to many relationship with the following models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :issues, through: :interests
end

class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts, through: :interests
end

class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :issue
end
```

When I try to call the following method in my `accounts_controller`

```
def add_issue
  issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
  @account = current_user.account
  @account.interests.create(issue: issue)
end
```

I get an error reading `undefined method 'interests' for #<Account:0x007fe50e23b658>`. What is the proper way to go about posting to a join table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method 'interests' for #<Account:0x007fe50e23b658>

You need to add the association `has_many :interests` as well in the models

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :interests
  has_many :issues, through: :interests
end

class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :interests
  has_many :accounts, through: :interests
end
```

I suggest you to read [*HMT*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association

Comment: This was the missing piece. So if I want to leverage any many-to-many relationship, I also need to specify that there is a relationship with the join table itself?

Comment: @d00medman With the `has_many :trough`, that is how it should be. With `has_and_belongs_to_many` the things are slightly different :)